# How to write a RavenDB index as a prefiltered list of documents, not searchable

Tags: ravendb

I want to get a list of users filtered by a property (string) being null or empty.

I've created an index for this but I'm not sure if my way of implementing it is the right way to do it.

```
public class Users_Contributors : AbstractIndexCreationTask<User>
{
    public Users_Contributors()
    {
        Map = users => from user in users
                       where user.ContributionDescription != null && user.ContributionDescription != "" 
                       select new {};
    }
}
```

So I just want raven to "prepare" the list of users for me. I'm just gonna get all user objects out of that index with no additional filtering/where criterias at query time.

Is the above code the way to go or can I achieve the same in a better way? Im feeling Im missing something here. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will work just fine.  The result would be that the index only contains users that have something in their `ContributionDescription` field.

If you want to make it slightly easier to read, you can use `string.IsNullOrEmpty`, but that won't have any impact on performance.

```
Map = users => from user in users
               where !string.IsNullOrEmpty(user.ContributionDescription)
               select new {};
```

It probably feels strange because of the empty object at the end, but that just defines the index entries.  If you aren't sorting or filtering by any other field, then using an empty object is just fine.  Keep in mind that the `__document_id` entry gets created regardless of what fields you map.